# HTML collection getting parsed to JavaScript through PHP when it should be a String

Tags: javascript, php, parsing, htmlcollection

### I have a database that I use to create a resource of string values for example

### |Boxers|1|

### |Shirts|2|

etc
I then use php to populate a array with this resource
eg

```
$myArr = arrary['Boxers', '1', 'Shirts', 2]
```

then I parse the array as a JavaScript array through an echo and .push() each element within a for loop

This JS array then becomes the argument of a JS function call.
As you can see below.

```
<?php
            if(isset($_SESSION["username"])){

                $cartArr = array();
                $sql = "SELECT item, quantity FROM shop_cart WHERE user = 'Mike'";
                $result = $conn->query($sql);
                if($result->num_rows > 0){    
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        array_push($cartArr,$row["item"],$row["quantity"]);
                    }
                }    

                echo '<script> let paramArr = [];';

                for($x = 0; $x < count($cartArr); $x++){
                    echo 'paramArr.push(' . "$cartArr[$x]" . ');';
                }


                echo 'cleanUpVue(paramArr);

                </script>';
            }
    ?>
```

The problem is that every element that is a String such as Boxers, Shirts keeps getting parsed as an HTML Collection and not just as a String. I'd like to know what I can do to avoid this behavior? As all I need is a JS array of String elements (4 as per the example) and nothing else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

terrible what an obvious oversight on my part, I simply forgot to include quotation marks before concatenating the variable name, as such JS was trying to evaluate the original Strings as they also matched id's within the DOM

```
 for($x = 0; $x < count($cartArr); $x++){
                    echo 'paramArr.push("' . $cartArr[$x] . '");';
                }
```